# fbsdk - Android - compile failed - AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name

Tags: android, react-native-fbsdk

React native 0.44
FBSDK 0.6

I am getting the following when compiling Android:

```
/home/.../app/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/values-v24/values-v24.xml:3: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.

/home/.../app/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/values-v24/values-v24.xml:4: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.

/home/.../app/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/values-v24/values-v24.xml:3: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.

/home/../app/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/values-v24/values-v24.xml:4: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.


:react-native-fbsdk:processReleaseResources FAILED
```

Comment: Project Build.gradle:
 android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mytest3"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22


dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    compile project(':react-native-maps')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"

Comment: FBSDK Build.gradle . 
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'